# Java: Handling Client Timeout at Server Side

Tags: java, sockets, timeout, serversocket

I use blocking IO sockets. My client sends a message and then waits for the response from the server. I now want to introduce a read timeout at the client side but I am confused what to do at the server side. Here's some pseudo code:

```
Client:
while(true) {
  sendRequest();
  readResponse();
}

Server:
while(true) {
  readRequest();
  handleRequest();
  sendResponse();
}
```

Suppose the client sends a request and catches a timeout exception. However the server is still processing the request and wants to send the response. Before that happening the client already sent a second request.

I am afraid things will get out of order this way. What is a server typically supposed to do in this case? Can I catch on the server side that the client got a timeout and then decide not to send the response?

greetings,
jan